# Virtual Machine Scale set in Azure doesn't scale

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

Virtual Machine scale set in Azure doesn't scale. The CPU usage on the VM is 99%, but the utilziation shown on Azure for only one is around 10%-20%.

I have tried adjusting the scale lower for the average cpu to 40%, but it doesn't change anything.

When the virtual machine starts, there is a load of around %80-90 instantly from my code. The scale set should scale to a second machine after 5 minutes and keep repeating until the load decreases and all runs are complete. What happens the machine starts and if you RDP to the machine, task manager shows the process using 80-90% cpu constantly. If you view Azure to see the scale set as a whole it only list 10-20% cpu usage. The virtual machine is a server 2016 core edition built-in to Azure. It is almost like it isn't reporting back to azure the CPU usage, so it never scales beyond 1 maybe 2 every once in a while.

Comment: it also depends upon how you've configured your scale in rules, Also scale out happens when the average CPU of all the machines in the scale set is exceeded.

Comment: If I lower the average percentage to 18 for the scale up and set the scale down to 10 everything works. It’s just odd that with one machine running at 100% the scale set only reports 20% usage. The thing that is even more odd is once the other machines scale up the average cpu seems about normal. It’s like it’s a bug with a single machine.